# Android. How can I change a ListView text color on click?

Tags: android, listview, colors

I change the color with this code, but the color changes only when i quit from the application and run it again. How can I resolve to change immediately the color?

```
adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Create `res/color/button_text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout `XML` will apply the color list to a `View`:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

And if you want to apply `State Color` Dynamically then

```
ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                    new int[][]{
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, //1
                            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, //2
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_pressed} //3
                    },
                    new int[] {
                        Color.RED, //1
                        Color.WHITE, //2
                        Color.BLUE //3
                    }
                );
            title_txt.setTextColor(myColorStateList);
```

For more information go to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: And what if I can choose from 5 color, but in XML can define only two state, pressed and focused. In this way does not work, I think.

Comment: @user3399567 you can defined a state with color. many states are there. go to the link for more information.thnx

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of state, but I need to change color only in pressed state, I can't define one color with pressed state, another with focused. Every color need to changed on pressed state.

Comment: @user3399567 then remove the state as you not required.

Comment: No, you don't understand. I have 5 button separately. Every button define a color. When I press a button the ListView need to to selected color on pressed state.

Comment: Ok i got you but first clear to to me how your button color logic is work?

Comment: So, I have 5 button, every button represent a color. When I click on one of them the displayed ListView's color need to be changed for the selected button's color.

Comment: @user3399567 it's simple. used my Dynamically color state logic and change second color to  `Color.WHITE, //2----> your color`

Comment: @user3399567 that is your ListView adapter text

Answer (score 4):

Put this file in res/color folder as `textselector_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<!-- selected -->
<item android:color="#FF888888"/>
<!-- default -->
```

And set this as `android:textColor="@color/textselector_list"` to the `listView` item i.e. your `TextView` or `Button`.