# Android Change Text color in base adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have list view, that set on base adapter like following :

```
                FQAdapter fa=new FQAdapter(FQActivity2.this, al);
                lvfq.setAdapter(fa);
                lvfq.setDivider(null);
```

In my base adapter inflater xml file have two field , text and image :  i want to when i click on image at that time whatever text are with that, text change  their color like following :

```
       @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;             //trying to reuse a recycled view
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (vi == null) 
        { 
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater lif=( LayoutInflater ) ctx.getSystemService ( ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ) ;
            vi=lif.inflate(R.layout.item_fq, null);
            holder.tvMsg=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_username);
            holder.ivMinuse=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_un_minuse);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        final FAQ jou=al.get(position);

        holder.tvMsg.setText(jou.getFqTitle());
        holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // here i want to set text color whatever image click
                // like holder.setivMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); but it effect on only last text of list
                new GetAns().execute("url"+jou.getFqId());
                //Log.v("dssfs", jou.getFqAns());
            }
        });

        //date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, true);

        return vi ;
    }
```

as i write on code comment i want to change text color holder.tvMsg of perticular position when click on holder.ivMinuse image;

Please help me to do this

**Edit :
My entire java file :**

```
     public class FQActivity extends Activity{
ImageView ivChcklistUnsel;
ImageView ivJourUnsel;
ImageView ivResourUnsel;
ImageView ivRecipUnsel;
ImageView ivSettingUnsel;
ImageView ivFaqUnsel;

ImageView ivChcklistsel;
ImageView ivJoursel;
ImageView ivResoursel;
ImageView ivRecipsel;
ImageView ivSettingsel;
ImageView ivFaqsel;

ListView lvfq;
ArrayList<FAQ> al;
TextView tvAns;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fq_layout);
    initImageview();
    tvAns=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ans);
    tvAns.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    lvfq=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_fqlistview);
    new GetJournal().execute(Appconstants.SERVICE_URL1+"faq/getFaqData");
}
public class GetJournal extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(FQActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Please Wait</b><br/>loading..."));
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return new DownloadAdapter(FQActivity.this).getJSONData(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.cancel();
        try 
        {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
            Log.v("dd", result);
            if(obj.getString("status").equals("success"))
            {
                JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONArray("response");
                al=new ArrayList<FAQ>();
                FAQ fq;
                for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
                {
                    obj=arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    fq=new FAQ();
                    Log.v("dd", obj.getString("faq_title"));
                    fq.setFqId(obj.getString("faq_id"));
                    fq.setFqTitle(obj.getString("faq_title"));
                    //fq.setFqQue(obj.getString("faq_qus"));
                    //fq.setFqAns(obj.getString("faq_ans"));
                    al.add(fq);
                }

                FQAdapter fa=new FQAdapter(FQActivity.this, al);
                lvfq.setAdapter(fa);
                lvfq.setDivider(null);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("response"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class GetAns extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(FQActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Please Wait</b><br/>loading..."));
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return new DownloadAdapter(FQActivity.this).getJSONData(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.cancel();
        try 
        {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
            Log.v("dd", result);
            if(obj.getString("status").equals("success"))
            {
                JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONArray("response");

                    obj=arr.getJSONObject(0);
                    tvAns.setText(obj.getString("faq_ans"));

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("response"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private void initImageview()
{
    ivChcklistsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_checklist_sel);
    ivChcklistsel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ivJoursel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_jour_sel);
    ivResoursel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_resour_sel);
    ivRecipsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_recipes_sel);
    ivFaqsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_faq_sel);
    ivFaqsel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ivSettingsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_setting_sel);

    ivChcklistUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_checklist_unsel);
    ivChcklistUnsel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ivJourUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_jour_unsel);
    ivResourUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_resour_unsel);
    ivRecipUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_recipes_unsel);
    ivFaqUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_faq_unsel);
    ivFaqUnsel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ivSettingUnsel= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_setting_unsel);

    ivChcklistUnsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyCheckListActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    ivResourUnsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResourceActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    ivRecipUnsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipesActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    ivJourUnsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyJournalActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    ivSettingUnsel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppSettingActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public class FQAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<FAQ> al;

    int i1=0;
    public FQAdapter(Context cxt,ArrayList<FAQ> al)
    {
        this.ctx=cxt;
        this.al=al;  
     }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;             //trying to reuse a recycled view
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (vi == null) 
        { 
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater lif=( LayoutInflater ) ctx.getSystemService ( ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ) ;
            vi=lif.inflate(R.layout.item_fq, null);
            holder.tvMsg=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_username);
            holder.ivMinuse=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_un_minuse);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        final FAQ jou=al.get(position);

        holder.tvMsg.setText(jou.getFqTitle());
        holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // i try here all your answeres code but not working
                new GetAns().execute("url"+jou.getFqId());
                //Log.v("dssfs", jou.getFqAns());
            }
        });

        //date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, true);

        return vi ;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvMsg;
        ImageView ivMinuse;
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

holder.tvMsg  give error to create final so i also try with global declaration .
nothing work for me to clcik and change color .. all work on last postion text ot image.

Comment: You need to keep track of clicked item's position. Then get view by position and set text color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352658/android-how-can-i-change-a-listview-text-color-on-click

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder= new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_xml, null);
     holder.ivMinuse=  convertView.findViewbyId(R.id.YourImageId);
      holder.tvMsg=  convertView.findViewbyId(R.id.YourTextId);
     convertView.setTag(ViewHolder);
      } else {

     holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
       holder.ivMinuse.settag(position);
        holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Integer.ParseInt(v.getTag.toString)==position)
                {
                   holder.tvMsg.setTextColor(YOUR_COLOR_HERE);
                }

            new GetAns().execute("url"+jou.getFqId());
            //Log.v("dssfs", jou.getFqAns());
        }
    });
```

but better to write your click listenr out side of the get view

```
          class  ViewHolder {
                TextView  tvMsg;
                 ImageView ivMinuse;
             }
```

Comment: position and tag both getting right but it only affect to last text not any in between

Comment: i edited the Answer.follow the view holder concept in adapter.You will definitely get the solution.Just follow above like and return the convertView like `return convertView;`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways :

**1.**  Keep track of clicked item

```
Integer clickPosition =-1;

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if( clickPosition ==  position)
        {
            holder.setivMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else{
            // default color
            holder.setivMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // set the position 
            clickPosition = position;

            new GetAns().execute("url"+jou.getFqId());
            //Log.v("dssfs", jou.getFqAns());
        }
    });
  }
```

**2.**  Set position as Tag in TextView

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       // Set Tag
       holder.setivMsg.setTag(position);

       holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               TextView txtListItem =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
               // get Tag
               if (position == (Integer)txtListItem.getTag())
                {
                    holder.setivMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else{
                    // default color
                    holder.setivMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
             }
        });
  }
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: Helloe @SweetWisher  i post my entire java file, if u find any mistake , i dont know why  nothing work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this,

```
 private int mSelectedPos = -1;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;             //trying to reuse a recycled view
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (vi == null) 
        { 
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater lif=( LayoutInflater ) ctx.getSystemService ( ctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ) ;
            vi=lif.inflate(R.layout.item_fq, null);
            holder.tvMsg=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_username);
            holder.ivMinuse=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_un_minuse);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        final FAQ jou=al.get(position);
        if(mSelectedPos == position){
          holder.tvMsg.setColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
          holder.tvMsg.setColor(yourDefaultColor);
         }
        holder.ivMinuse.setTag(position);
        holder.tvMsg.setText(jou.getFqTitle());
        holder.ivMinuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mSelectedPos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                new GetAns().execute("url"+jou.getFqId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        //date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, true);

        return vi ;
    }
```